# Position div inside navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position a website title (div) to the left of my navigation bar. I thought of creating another

```
<li><a>
```

element and put that as the website title, but I don't want it to have some of the propertise like font family and hover.

This is currently what I have:
[image: Nav Bar Preview 1]

and this is what I would like to achieve:
[image: Preview 2]

**So in summary I would like to add a div to put my website title to the left of the navigation buttons.**

```css
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #3D3D3D;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav li {
  float: left;
}
#nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
#nav li a:hover {
  color: #FF4343;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Prev 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Prev 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Prev 1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got too much in your CSS. Just changing the `ul` to:

```
 display:inline;
```

and then setting some line-height does the trick.

See this fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/x20mkx1n/5/ where I've taken out much of your CSS.

Comment: You've completely nuked OPs `1000px` container with this!

Comment: I simply removed the width as it wasn't relevant to the solution. The entire structure could be placed into another div that was set to 1000px and have the same background color as the interior.